# Do minor syntax error edit suggestions get rejected and discouraged?

Tags: discussion

I was looking at a [useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46719000/5037430) and found a minor ternary operator syntax error which I suggested an edit for:

```js
// Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
num = typeof(num) == 'number' && num % 1 === 0 : num : 0; 
                                               ^
// Fix:
num = typeof(num) == 'number' && num % 1 === 0 ? num : 0;
```

Of course, edits must be at least 6 characters, so I had to do some minor format changes. (like adding `<!-- language: lang-js -->` or `<!-- language: lang-none -->`)

But my edit was [immediately rejected by the first reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20776974), even though I mentioned in the edit comment:

```
fix syntax error for num ternary operator
```

So it left me wondering, do minor syntax error edit suggestions get rejected and discouraged?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

This edit is fine, and it shouldn't have gotten a reject vote in my opinion.

However, sometimes, such edits do get rejected. There might be plenty reasons, such as the reviewers not being knowledgeable on the subject (bad reason, they should filter their queue), mistaking an answer for a question (obviously, you shouldn't edit out errors in questions), accidentally miss-clicking, etc.

Don't be discouraged by reject votes or rejected edits. Instead, read and ask on meta if what you're doing is okay, and keep up the good work.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you.